# How can I determine the positioning of UIWebView from IB when it has been initialized in code?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview, interface-builder

I have successfully embedded a vimeo video using a UIWebView. However because i have created this in code, i have to adjust the positioning in code and i would prefer to do it through interface builder. Correct me if im wrong, i read that initializing UIWebView with the `initWithCoder` method was the way to achieve this. However i am not to sure how to properly make use of this method, if it is at all the right one.

Here is a bit code to show what i have been doing so far:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self embedVimeo:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/19969613" frame:CGRectMake(300, 100, 260, 200)];
[self embedVimeo:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/19967404" frame:CGRectMake(100, 300, 260, 200)];}


- (void)embedVimeo:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<iframe src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></iframe>\
</body></html>";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
/*UIWebView **/ videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

[[[videoView subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];
[mainView addSubview:videoView];
[videoView release];
```

}

Any ideas?

Tod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that the `initWithCoder` is automatically used by the Objective-C runtime/Cocoa/CocoaTouch to accomplish what you are aiming at. So you don't have to really worry about it.

In short, if you create you UI in IB, say instantiate there a UIWebView object, define its connection a controller of yours, then you will be able to use that UIWebView directly without worrying about having to instantiate it.

What I would do is:

1. creating a new Web View in my nib;
2. a controller/delegate for the WebView;
3. connect the WebView delegate to the controller/delegate;
4. connect the controller/delegate view to the WebView;
5. connect the rootViewController of the main window to the controller/delegate.

Once you make sure you have defined correctly all the outlets and connection, my simply loading this nib (which in case it is the MainMenu is done automatically), you'll have all of those objects instantiated and ready to be used (by calling `loadHTMLString:` or whatever.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks alot sergio, Sounds good, i am going to try your method now.

Comment: that was very useful, its working all fine now. Just one thing do you know how to remove the grey lines that appear on the edges of the vimeo embed, it seems to be some sort of glitch. I think it is also specific to vimeo since they did not appear on youtube.  Any ideas?

Comment: no worries, i figured out the problem. A slight adjustment of the margin size in the vimeo embedded code did the trick.